# Jquery not able to find checkbox ID or Name

Tags: jquery, checkbox, attr

I've got a page of checkbox that are styled.
I'm trying to return their name or ID when they are changed.

I've created a fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/xpq8g13s/

That shows the issue. The jquery I'm using is :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(this).change(function() {
        alert($(this).attr("name"));
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
    });
});
```

Can anyone advise why this isn't working ?

Thanks

Comment: This refers to document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this).change(function() {...` is looking for the `document` change event, so when you refer to `this` later on, it is trying to get the `name` and `id` attributes of the `document`.

Use this event binding instead

```
$("#check").change(function() {
  ...
```

Sample

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    alert($(this).attr("name"));
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
  });
});
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 53px;
  height: 19px
}
.switch input {
  display: none
}
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s
}
.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 11px;
  width: 19px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s
}
input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #008c00
}
input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3
}
input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px)
}
input,
select,
textarea {
  border: 1px solid #A0A0A0;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 3px 4px;
  color: #222;
  margin: 2px 5px 2px 0px;
}
input:focus,
select:focus,
textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#' class='tooltip' title='tooltip text.'>
  <img src='images/tooltip.png'>
</a>&nbsp;<b>This is my Text Label:</b>
</div>&nbsp;

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" name='check' id='check' title='checkbox' value="1">
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label>

<br/>
<input type="text" id="textinput" name="textinput" size="40" maxlength="40" autocomplete="off" placeholder="enter text here" value="" tabindex='1' disabled/>
</div>
<br/>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" name='check2' id='check2' title='checkbox' value="1">
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks - I have many checkboxes on the page.. How can I use this to work with which ever is selected ?

Comment: You would simply change the selector to target all of the checkboxes, check out my updated example

Comment: Thanks I'd just come up with similar..   `$("input[name^='chk']").change(function() {
        alert($(this).attr("name"));
    });`

Comment: That might work too, but I'd just use the type="checkbox" selector. That'll ensure you don't have to fiddle around with the name properties of each one

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xpq8g13s/1/    if checked then changes its name to check and if unchecked then name becomes unchekced

Answer (score 0):

Try it like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.yourChkboxsClassName').change(function() {
    alert($('.yourChkboxsClassName').attr("name"));
    alert($('.yourChkboxsClassName').attr("id"));
});
});
```

Set a unique class name for all of your checkboxes and use that in your code instead of yourChkboxsClassName.

With

> this

you just refer to the scope in which your function is defined.